# matplotlib.pyplot 2.0.0 shows empty plots during run time

Tags: python, matplotlib

Minimum example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

def plot(array):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(array)
    plt.show()

for i in range(5):
    plot(np.linspace(-10.*i, 10*i, num=101))

time.sleep(15)
```

This creates 5 plots and then waits 15 seconds until termination. The plot windows appear, but during these 15 seconds you can see the frames of the plot windows, but the content is transparent (you see the content of other windows below; see attached picture).
This happened after an upgrade to matplotlib to version 2.0.0.

I want the plots to be visible before the program terminates and this was possible before (at least in an ipython console of the spyder IDE). What do I have to adjust?

[Screenshot of transparent plot windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS613.png)

edit:

Python 2.7.12

matplotlib 2.0.0

ipython: 5.1.0

Comment: You might want to check if you have anything in your `matplotlibrc` file that could be affecting things. Also note that the default location has moved from `.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` to `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`, so it might be that its not being read in at all.

Comment: Thank you, but for what exactly should I be looking?

Comment: In /home/.../.config/matplotlib/ is no file at all.

Comment: @BeateBier I am experimenting similar issues with qt backends. As a workaround you might try a different one, I suggest TkAgg.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using interactive mode, you should use `plt.pause` instead of `time.sleep`. The following works for me,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

def plot(array):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(array)
    plt.show()


for i in range(5):
    plot(np.linspace(-10.*i, 10*i, num=101))

plt.pause(15)
```

Generally with interactive plots, I find it works more reliably if you specify the figure and axis `ax` at the beginning, `plt.show` them and use `ax.plots` to update it with `plt.draw` and `plt.pause` used whenever you need to update the display. For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5,1)
plt.ion()
plt.show()

def plot(ax, array):
    ax.plot(array)
    plt.draw()

for i in range(5):
    plot(axs[i], np.linspace(-10.*i, 10*i, num=101))

plt.pause(15)
```

Comment: Hm, what does it do? It shows the plots immediately and then it waits, but the time seems to be less than 15 seconds.
In my actual program I don't use time.sleep(). I have other code running and while it is running I want to be able to look at the plots created before. This was possible before the upgrade.

Comment: I see the plot, whereas the `time.sleep` opens a figure but doesn't draw anything (matplotlib 1.4.3). Does this not work for you? If not, you may need to call `plt.draw()` again after each plot...

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't complete before. It worked (before the upgrade) in the IPython console of the spyder IDE. Whether it worked in a regular ipython console I cannot say. (Edited the original question.)
I used:
`for i in range(3):
 plot(np.linspace(-10.*i, 10*i, num=101))
plt.pause(1)
for i in range(3):
 plot(np.linspace(-10.*i, 10*i, num=101))`

Comment: The update to matplotlib doesn't appear to make any changes that should effect this behaviour but different backends do different things or it may be a in issue between spyder IDE interactive mode with matplotlib 2.0 (which I guess could be reported as a bug). The draw docs http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=ion#matplotlib.pyplot.draw suggest `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` instead of draw. If this doesn't work then add spyder tag to question and hopefully someone who uses this can help.

Comment: Actually it works. I'm using plt.pause(0.1), which is just displaying the plots and then my program is going on.
But what is this command actually doing? And why doesn't it work with the ordinary plt.show()?

Comment: Hm. `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` does not work. Until now, just the plt.pause() thing is working.

Comment: Oh, I see. Normally show creates the figure, draws everything and blocks so no more code is executed until you close the figure. In interactive mode, show no longer blocks so there is no time for a new plot command to actually update the figure. From pause docs (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pause "If there is an active figure it will be updated and displayed, and the GUI event loop will run during the pause." and "If there is no active figure, or if a non-interactive backend is in use, this executes time.sleep(interval)"